# How to put more than one image by page using img2pdf?

Tags: bash, pdf, image-conversion

I have a series of images (>100) that I want to print in a specific size, that size let me put 8 of the images in a page, but when running the next command I get one image by page.

```bash
img2pdf *.png --pagesize letter --border 2cm --imgsize 6.3cmx8.8cm --fit shrink --output cards.pdf
```

what I'm missing in the command to allow the layout I desire (2 columns of 4 images)?

PD: I have read the [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/img2pdf/img2pdf.1.en.html) but I don't find anything about it, don't know if is even possible

Answer (score 1):

Use `ImageMagick`'s tool `montage`.
If your files are named like so:
0.png 1.png 2.png 3.png 4.png 5.png 6.png 7.png

```
[0-7].png -tile 2x4 -geometry +0+0 0-7_montage.png && img2pdf 0-7_montage.png --pagesize letter --border 2cm --imgsize 6.3cmx8.8cm --fit shrink --output cards.pdf
```

Update:
This is how you process 100 images.
Change 100 in `for i in {0..100..8}; do` to your specific number.

**Sequential filename iteration:**

```
#!/bin/bash

output_dir="output_pdfs"

# Create the output directory if it doesn't exist
mkdir -p "$output_dir"

# Iterate over sets of 8 images
for i in {0..100..8}; do
    input_images=$(seq -f "%d.png" $i $((i+7)))

    montage $input_images -tile 2x4 -geometry 332x238+5+5 "$output_dir/montage_output_$i.png"
    img2pdf --pagesize letter --imgsize 669 --output "$output_dir/cards_$i.pdf" --fit shrink "$output_dir/montage_output_$i.png"
done
```

**Update, again:** This proved to be VERY picky about filename. So, here's a version that is, mostly, filename bulletproof. Will accept both `png` & `jpg` format.

**Iterate all filenames alphabetically:**

```
#!/bin/bash

output_dir="output_pdfs"

# Create the output directory if it doesn't exist
mkdir -p "$output_dir"

# Get a sorted list of image filenames (with quotes)
image_files=($(ls -1Q *.{jpg,png} | sort))

# Iterate over sets of 8 images
for ((i = 0; i < ${#image_files[@]}; i += 8)); do
    input_images=("${image_files[@]:i:8}")

    echo "Processing images: ${input_images[@]}"
    montage "${input_images[@]}" -tile 2x4 -geometry 332x238+5+5 "$output_dir/montage_output_$i.jpg"
    img2pdf --pagesize letter --imgsize 669 --output "$output_dir/cards_$i.pdf" --fit shrink "$output_dir/montage_output_$i.png"
done
```

Save to: `montage_to_pdf.sh`
Change mode to executable: `chmod +x montage_to_pdf.sh`
Usage: `montage_to_pdf.sh`

Run inside the directory with your images.

Comment: How would this  work with 100+ images?

Comment: @Destroy666 I've updated the answer showing how to do 100+ images.

Comment: How could I ensure the tiles generated from `montage` have the desired size (6.3cmx8.8cm)? Also the `--imgsize 6.3cmx8.8cm` inside the img2pdf command will resize the whole `output_dir/montage_output_$i.png` I think it should be removed from the command and handle the size of the tile with imagemagic.

Comment: I got it working based on your scrip, the commands should change to `montage $input_images -tile 2x4 -geometry 332x238+5+5 "$output_dir/montage_output_$i.png"` where the 332x238 is 6.3x8.8 cm but in px with a space of 5px and `img2pdf --pagesize letter --imgsize 669 --output cards.pdf --fit shrink "$output_dir/montage_output_$i.png"` where the `imgsize` is the addition of 332 (tile side size) by 2 (columns count) plus 5 (spacing) and the `--fit shrink` is requires so `img2pdf` don't scale up the image, it will respect the aspect ratio, I did print a test page w/o margins & it worked perfctly

Comment: also, you can move the `img2pdf` command outside of the loop to generate only one pdf with all the pages `img2pdf --pagesize letter --imgsize 669 --output cards.pdf --fit shrink montage_output_*.png`